# What is self similarity test in image processing?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

What is a self similarity test in image processing?

Why is the self similarity test used?

How we can one do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self similarity of an image is the degree to which different regions in an image mimic each other.

Possible application areas are compression or object recognition or denoising.

Usually one defines a similarity measure (mean square error, structural similarity index, ..) and agrees on a set of possible transformations between regions (translation or affine,...) and then by some method tries to find all possible sets of similar regions within the chosen measure. For example, cross-correlations between regions can give first hints.

For more information see for example the thesis [Self-Similarity of Images and Non-local Image Processing](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/handle/10012/6019).

Comment: Is the distance between the encoding of 2 images considered a self similarity measure?

Comment: @Noran it will always depend on the application, but why not.